# Porque no funciona este diccionario?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, input

Cuando uso un prompt para la entrada de datos funciona. Sin embargo cuando uso input no.Es un diccionario en donde quiero que Cuando las personas personas escriban una palabra salgan sis y características. Pero con input no me quiere funcionar...
Quien sabe como reparar este problema?..
Lo que deseo es simple: entrar una palabra en sueco o español a traves del imput y dar de salida las características de la palabra asi como su traducción(la cual es una se sus características).Es decir que la palabra a buscar se pueda escribir en cualquiera de los dos idiomas y sin importar si se escribe en mayúsculas o minúscula.

Gracias

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA- 
    Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>Escriba la Palabra:
    <input type="text" 
     name="palabra" id="palabra" 
    maxlength="20" autofocus>
    <br>
    <input type="button" 
    name="Buscar" value="Buscar" 
    onclick="busqueda()">
    </form>


    <script>
        var palabras = [

            {
                articulo: "",
                palabrasueca: 
    "kläder",
                clase: "Sustantivo",
                palabraespa: "ropa"
            }, {
                articulo: "",
                palabrasueca: 
    "data",
                clase: "Sustantivo",
                palabraespa: "datos"
            }, {
                articulo: "",
                palabrasueca: 
    "böter",
                clase: "Sustantivo",
                palabraespa: "multa"
            },]

    function busqueda() {
            var nolo = "No tenemos 
    registrada esa palabra"
            var texto = document.getElementById("palabra").value;
            texto = 
    texto.toLowerCase()
            if (texto == palabraespa 
    || texto == palabrasueca) {


                const resultado = 
    palabras.find(palabra => 
    palabra.palabraespa == texto)
                document.write(" 
     Nombre " + 
    resultado.palabraespa + " 
    <br>" + " Categoria  " + 
    resultado.clase + " " + "<br>" + 
    "traduccion " + 
     resultado.palabrasueca + "<br>" 
      + 
    "Articulo: " + " " + 
    resultado.articulo)
            } else {
                document.write(nolo)
            }
    </script>
    </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: Tienes errores en busqueda()... tienes una condicion en donde comparas con una variable que no existe: `if (texto == palabraespa)`, hasta ese momen to no has hecho uso del array de posibles palabras.

Comment: Es que lo que trataba de expresar en esa condición era que el texto de entrada pueda ser cualquier palabra contenida en la propiedad: palabraespa o palabrasueca

Comment: Si, es lo que trato de decirte... lo que debes hacer es recorrer ese array y para cada elemento hacer esa comparacion...

Comment: Como harias eso ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así

```js
//En esta variable escribimos el resultado
const Resultado = document.getElementById("Resultado");

var palabras = [

    {
        articulo: "",
        palabrasueca: "kläder",
        clase: "Sustantivo",
        palabraespa: "ropa"
    }, {
        articulo: "",
        palabrasueca: "data",
        clase: "Sustantivo",
        palabraespa: "datos"
    }, {
        articulo: "",
        palabrasueca: "böter",
        clase: "Sustantivo",
        palabraespa: "multa"
    }];

function busqueda(texto) {
    let palabra = GetPalabra(texto);

    if (palabra != null) {
        Resultado.innerHTML =
            `Español : ${palabra.palabraespa}<br />
        Sueco : ${palabra.palabrasueca}<br />
        Clase : ${palabra.clase}<br />`;
    }
    else {
        Resultado.innerHTML = "No tenemos registrada esa palabra";
    }
}

//Recorre el array y pregunta si el texto ingresado
//coincide con su versión en español y o en sueco y 
//retorna el primer valor encontrado. 
//En caso de no encontrar nada retorna null 
function GetPalabra(texto) {
    for (let p of palabras) {
        if (p.palabrasueca == texto || p.palabraespa == texto) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

```html
Escriba la Palabra:
<input type="text" name="palabra" id="palabra" maxlength="20" autofocus>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Buscar" value="Buscar" onclick="busqueda(palabra.value)">
<div id="Resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias...Era lo que buscaba....

Comment: Procura siempre ofrecer una breve explicación de por qué este código resuelve la pregunta. Piensa no sólo en el OP sino en los que vean esta misma pregunta en el futuro :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Qué es el OP?

Comment: _OriginalPoster_, se traduce como _quien pregunta_.

Comment: @Alfabravo Muchas gracias, podrías haber colocado eso. Piensa no solo en los usuarios antiguos si no que en los nuevo :P

Comment: Bueno, entonces ya que entendiste, mejora la respuesta! :)